# Find all numbes $1\le a\le n-1$ which are prime to n and they are not witness Fermat of compositeness of n

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, cryptography, primality-test

Given the number $n=35$.Find all numbes $1\le a\le n-1$ which are prime to n and they are not witness Fermat of compositeness of n

I found this problem on internet and i am trying to find a solution but i can't find anything.It would be very nice if we can get a proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of attacking this is to note that the requirements on $a$ is that, for all prime factors $p$ of $n$:

$$a^{n-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$$

If we go through the prime factors of $n$ (5, 7), we find that the above is equivalent to:

$$a \equiv \{1, 4\} \pmod{5}$$
$$a \equiv \{1, 6\} \pmod{7}$$

By the Chinese remainder theorem, that implies that there are four such solutions for $a$, namely $\{ 1, 6, 29, 34 \}$

Comment: these solutions of a, except that they are primes to n=35 , are they not witness Fermat of compositeness?

Comment: @paris: they all have $a^{34} = 1 \pmod{35}$, and hence they are not Fermat witnesses.  Reminder: the Fermat test for compositeness is $a^{n-1} \ne 1 \pmod{n}$; if we find an $a \ne 0 \pmod{n}$ where this is true, then we've shown that $n$ is composite.  An $a$ that doesn't show this is a Fermat nonwitness.